# Android Studio 2: Google Play dependencies error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just switched to Android Studio 2 and I'm trying to use Google Play services in my app. But I faced a really strange from the very beginning. Adding to Gradle.build such dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
```

cause error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /media/valentyn/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/workspace/Studio Projects
16.02.16/LocalVenues/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-maps/8.4.0/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory) Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Can it be some conflict with installed libraries in SDK Manager or what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same kind of problem, caused by the new [Instant Run](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run) in Android Studio 2, I solved it with:

- `Build` > `Rebuild Project`
- `Run` again.

Comment: Funny, it worked after the second rebuild:) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing that this issue was related to NTFS file system of my portable driver. After moved my project, this problem was solved.